# SAS Data Step / Pointer / Indirect Variable Assignment

Tags: sas

In a SAS Data Step i have a character variable called "varName". This variable stores the name of another variable. In below's example, it stores the name of the numeric variable "changeMe":

```
data TMP;
   length
      varName $32
      changeMe 8
      ;
   varName = ‘changeMe’;
   /*??? How to change the content of variable that varName holds ???*/
run;
```

Now the question is: how do i change the content of the variable that varName holds?

The use case would be that varName acts as a dynamic pointer to different variables that i want to manipulate in a big SAS Data Set.

Comment: Looks like you have a transaction file. Check out the UPDATE statement.  Also do you have the data in text file?  Check out the named input style. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p1jjrvmzmybdeqn1gt8gj1r0ed0u.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en  We used to use that for creating transaction datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATA Step does not directly provide for named indirect assignment.

In some cases, the indirect assignment requirement might indicate you want to perform a `Proc TRANSPOSE` data transformation. If the variable names and values are provided in a transaction data set, and the data has `BY` group variables, your better solution might be to `TRANSPOSE` the transaction data and merge that transform to the master data using an `UPDATE` or `MODIFY` statement.

Regardless, you can array variables of a given type and iterate the array looking for the target requiring assignment.

Example:

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class;

  varname = 'name';
  varvalue = 'Scooter';

  array chars _character_;

  do _n_ = 1 to dim(chars);
    if upcase (vname(chars(_n_))) = upcase(varname) then do;
      chars(_n_) = varvalue;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`call execute()` is a highly feasible solution.

```
data TMP;
   length
      varName $32
      changeMe 8
      ;
   varName = 'changeMe';
run;

data _null_;
  set TMP end=eof;

  if _n_ = 1 then call execute('data %trim(&syslast.); modify %trim(&syslast.);');
  call execute(cats(varName)||' = rand("uniform",1,0);');
  if eof then call execute('run;');
run;
```

Log:

```
NOTE: CALL EXECUTE generated line.
1   + data WORK.TMP; modify WORK.TMP;
2   + changeMe = rand("uniform",1,0);
3   + run;

NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.TMP.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TMP has been updated.  There were 1 observations rewritten, 0 observations
      added and 0 observations deleted.
```